# Android - sending data to a web service

Tags: android, android-service, android-volley, android-intentservice

I'm about to write an application that sends data to a server with a post request. These requests can fail and if they do I want them to be sent when the connection is back online.

What is the best way to implement this behavior?

**EDIT**
I've read some articles and come up with the following idea. I register a BroadcastReceiver in the manifest and tell it to listen for android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE and android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED. When the request can't be send I store the request. If the connection becomes alive then I will send the cached requests.

Comment: Could you show the code that have you tried? or the logcat with error?

Comment: Please post your code ?

Comment: Sorry I have no code yet. I'm figuring out what the best way is to write the code. I will edit my original question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to implement this behavior?

Make [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) requests from a [bound `Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), and send the result back to the `Activity` if it is still in the foreground.

**EDIT:**

> won't this be a problem if the user decides to close the application?

That's *exactly* why you need to use a `Service`. If you do it from an `Activity`, the request continues even when the `Activity` is dismissed. If your `Volley` request is expressed as an anonymous class instance, it continues to hold an implicit reference to the outer `Activity` class, which leads to a memory leak / exception.

Comment: won't this be a problem if the user decides to close the application?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Internet Connection continuously by using Handler or service ,if it is sends the data to the server otherwise dont send it.